# Reading order for Dragonlance?

Tags: suggested-order, dragonlance

I wanted to try out more of Weis and Hickman's works(I liked the Deathgate Cycle very much), and I decided to do it with Dragonlance. Since there are a lot of books in the series, can somebody clarify whether I should be reading in the chronological order or not?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would start with the [Chronicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_novels#The_Chronicles_Trilogy) and move on to the [Legends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_novels#Legends) series.   The [first set of Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_novels#Tales_I), which are collections of short stories, has some great side stories for the main characters and their children.

In my opinion the rest of the series doesn't match the quality of the first 6 books. So after you finish reading the first 6 and the first tales, one should probably read the rest of them in release date order.  Because a bunch of wars, world-changing epochs, and characters appear after the first 6 that are only tangentially related to the plots of the first 6.

I've read dozens of the Dragonlance novels by authors other than [Margaret Weis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Weis) and [Tracy Hickman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy_Hickman) and most of them are really not that great.  The [Preludes I and II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_novels#Preludes), are not written by Weis and Hickman, and you should only read them if you really love the characters.  In later novels, Weis and Hickman almost explicitly ret-con out the events of the Preludes novels, though a few plot-lines survive into [Dragons of Summer Flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_of_Summer_Flame).  This kind of creates a canon versus non-canon perspective of Preludes and other non-Weis and Hickman novels and stories.

The first [Chronicles novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_novels#The_Chronicles_Trilogy), [Dragons of Autumn Twilight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_of_Autumn_Twilight):

[image: The original cover of Dragons of Autumn Twilight]

Comment: You might also check out "The Deathgate cycle" series by Weis and Hickman.  It's a great example of a series that blurs the lines between fantasy and sci-fi... though I don't want to spoil it by saying more than that.

Comment: Also worth noting is that most of the Dragonlance books not written by Weis or Hickman are generally fairly low quality in comparison. (At least in my opinion) There are a few good ones, but I'd stick to the Weis & Hickman books.

Comment: @shadowission: Yes, I failed to mention that.  There are tons of novels in the series written by other authors.  With a few exceptions they are mostly not worth reading, unless you are really dying for more stories about particular characters.

Comment: Deathgate cycle is their only work that I have read and its quality the reason I am reading Dragonlance

Comment: Dragons of Summer Flame wraps up the whole companions timeline and moves onto the 5th age, this book mostly stars Palin, Steel with Tas and the rest having contributions (including Raistlin).

Answer (score 9):

I once did some research on this and compiled two reading order lists. The best resource I found (based partially on my own reading of about half the entire series myself) was the [recommended reading list on DLNexus](http://www.dlnexus.com/products/reading.aspx) and their [complete product list](http://www.dlnexus.com/products/list.aspx) which gives the chronological order.

Both would have you reading *Chronicles* and *Legends* first (including *Dragons of the Dwarven Depths* in second place [*Lost Chronicles Vol 1*, fills gap]), and then diverge after that. The recommended reading order goes on to *The Second Generation* rather than continuing in chronological order. After that would be *The Fifth Age* series' (*Dragons of a New Age*, and *The Dhamon Saga*), then the *Age of Mortals* (*War of Souls*, and *Dark Disciple*). By the time you get there you should have a pretty good idea of what direction you want to go if you want to break from the recommended reading order. I recommend not missing the Classic Supplemental novels. :)

Answer (score 7):

Mark Roger's answer of **Chronicles**, **Legends**, and **Tales** is a good answer.

Once you fall in love with these characters you are going to be tempted to read the **Preludes** books, which talk about the five years in which the companions were separated. These are terrible books which suffer greatly from continuity flaws and boring stories. This is also true of **Meetings**.

The more interesting Dragonlance books NOT written by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman are ones that deal with things far and away from the beloved main characters. Deep in the past or completely removed from the events in the first books.

Comment: I didn't think the Preludes were that bad.  I think they're still worthwhile (despite not being as good as the others).

Comment: @DVK Of course I was joking about getting all your rep. However, I will take your entire stockpile of unicorn blood.

Comment: @JackBNimble - unicorn blood has a shelf life of 1 day fresh, 3 days cold and 1 week frozen. My supply is down the drain :(